# How to import my db dump into mariadb on start?

Tags: wordpress, docker, mariadb

I have a docker-compose.yml file like this

```
version: '2'

services:

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: my_wp
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: my_user
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: my_pass
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html

  mysql:
    image: mariadb
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: my_pass
    volumes:
      - ./db:/etc/mysql
```

I can run my containsers using the command `docker-compose up` and it works fine, but shows the default wordpress site with empty db to setup. What I want is, I have a db dump file my_db.sql which I want to load into mariadb when its initializing. How can I do that? and where do I need to put my my_db.sql file to be picked by mariadb container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 options:

1. Mount your `.sql` file to `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/`

   ```
   version: '2'

   services:

     wordpress:
       image: wordpress
       ports:
         - 8080:80
       environment:
         WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: my_wp
         WORDPRESS_DB_USER: my_user
         WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: my_pass
       volumes:
         - ./src:/var/www/html

     mysql:
      image: mariadb
       environment:
         MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: my_pass
       volumes:
         - ./db:/etc/mysql
         - ./my_db.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/my_db.sql
   ```
2. Use build directive in your `docker-compose` file and point to a `dockerfile` with following content:

   ```
   FROM mysql
   COPY my_db.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
   ```
3. Create a dummy container, Mount `/my/own/datadir:/var/lib/mysql`, then restore the database manually using the `docker exec`, then you can use the host directory when ever you want that db in a container.

Comment: how exactly I need to update my docker-compose.yml file?

Comment: Added example to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Mount the folder with your sql files to `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` on the container in the `volumes` section of the db definitions. Any `.sql` (and `.sql.gz`) files will be automatically run in.

See the `Initializing a fresh instance` section of the [docs](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb/) for more info.